# Postgresql JDBC sometimes cannot select just inserted

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I use HikariDataSource to get connection and insert data into Postgresql, finally commit it. Then select with associated parameters, but not always can get results.

This is datasource create code:

```
      props.setProperty("dataSourceClassName","org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
      props.setProperty("dataSource.serverName", hostname);
      props.setProperty("dataSource.user", username);
      props.setProperty("dataSource.password", password);
      props.setProperty("dataSource.databaseName", database);
      props.setProperty("dataSource.portNumber", "5432");

      HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(props);
      config.setAutoCommit(false);

      datasource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

insert data code:

```
try {
  conn = datasource.getConnection();
  stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  int count = stat.executeUpdate();
} finally {
  stat.close();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
}
```

select code:

```
try {
  conn = datasource.getConnection();
  String sql = ... // sql with associated parameters
  stat = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql); // sometimes no result, need to wait a while.
  rs.close();
} finally {
  stat.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

The codes have no concurrent,
what I want is every insert can be selected and no wait.
Hopes anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: Most probably the SELECT runs before the `commit()` was called

Comment: Or - guessing since you didn't share your architecture - there is load balancing with standby servers, which are not synchronous.

Comment: I agree with the other comments. The thing is the commit may take some time to consolidate in the database server; sometimes more, sometimes less. If you call the `select` right away **using a separate connection** you may not see the row you just inserted (yet). If you used the **same** connection this problem won't happen and you would always see the new row, after the commit is complete.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't understand. I have commited the insert operation, 
and there no concurrent, just insert, commit and select in the only main thread.